# Sending a looped message in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I would like to make it so that once you do the command h!start, it sends you a message every 10 seconds and it stops when the user types h!stop. However, the discord bot never sends a message in the discord chat. I just started to learn how to make discord bots, so excuse me if this is basic. Error is under the code.

```py
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'h!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game('Work In Progress'))
    print('Bot is ready')

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def reminder():
    channel = client.get_channel(797915093954199565)
    await channel.send('It has been 10 seconds')

@client.command()
async def start():
    reminder.start()
    print('Reminder Started')

@client.command()
async def stop():
    reminder.cancel()
    print('Reminder stopped')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 942, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in process_commands
    await self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 856, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 790, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 693, in _parse_arguments
    raise discord.ClientException(fmt.format(self))
discord.errors.ClientException: Callback for start command is missing "ctx" parameter.
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-13' coro=<Loop._loop() done, defined at C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py:88> exception=NameError("name 'channel' is not defined")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 125, in _loop
    raise exc
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zedga\source\repos\Hydrate\Hydrate\Hydrate.py", line 16, in reminder
    await channel.send('It has been 10 seconds')
NameError: name 'channel' is not defined
Unhandled exception in internal background task 'reminder'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zedga\source\repos\Hydrate\Hydrate\Hydrate.py", line 16, in reminder
    await channel.send('It has been 10 seconds')
NameError: name 'channel' is not defined
```

Comment: `797915093954199565` probably isn't a channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah sure, just get the id of the channel the command was sent in and global it so it can be used in the task.

```py
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    global start_channel
    start_channel = ctx.channel.id
    reminder.start()
    print('Reminder Started')


@tasks.loop(seconds=4)
async def reminder():
    channel = client.get_channel(int(start_channel))
    await channel.send('It has been 10 seconds')


@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    reminder.cancel()
    print('Reminder stopped')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your error, it includes "channel not defined"

Its because it's channel is defined as a "local" variable, which means it can only be used in the same block of code or within the command. You can simply fix this by adding a global, A global makes a variable accessible throughout the whole code, it can be used like this:

```py
global channel
channel = client.get_channel(797915093954199565)
```

You are also missing the "ctx" decorator and your task should be below the below the command to trigger it

```py
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    reminder.start()
    print('Reminder Started')


@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def reminder():
    global channel
    channel = client.get_channel(797915093954199565)
    await channel.send('It has been 10 seconds')


@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    reminder.cancel()
    print('Reminder stopped')
```

Comment: is there a way to make it so that the bot does the reminder loop in the same channel that the command was in so that it can work in dms and any channel needed?

Comment: sure @Zeeshan check my recent answer